# android density indepence v2

Tags: android

I had a question about density independence that helped me create layouts for hdpi mdpi and ldpi densities. I created three folders with three layouts: layout-hdpi, layout-mdpi, layout-ldpi. In these densities there are different resolutions according to table on the bottom of the [developer site](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). I want my app to be used on tablets as well, so I created a new avd (WXGA 1280x800 medium density) but (of course) the layouts does not look like the way I want them to look like (they are somewhat smaller). How can I tell android in what cases what layouts to use? How should I name the folders? I just create a folder "layout-xl-mdpi", create the layout then Android will know that in case of 1280x800 resolution that layout should be used or what? 
One other thing: with these 3 layouts I cover the ldpi, mdpi, hdpi densities, but what about the resolution? small hdpi, normal hdpi, small ldpi, small mdpi etc. Or it doesn't matter? One layout is enough for "one cell" in the table below? There are 3 different resolutions for Extra Large screen with hdpi... What is the best practice?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something I call Android Asset hierarchy (Google may call the same, I forget), listed [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources). That determines what folder assets are used. Take a look at it.

Comment: So beyond my three folders, I should create a layout-sw600dp, layout-sw768dp, layout-sw1152dp etc? Still don't understand.

Comment: So, apart from ldpi, mdpi, hdpi folders, if your supporting tablets you should add xhdpi folder, and if there is a handset that doesnt fit neatly in these categories and is of 600dp width then add sw600dp folder, and other folders like this as needed. This can get confusing but if you keep it this simple and add new folders only when needed you should be ok.

Comment: so is it okay to have these folders: hdpi, ldpi, mdpi, xhdpi,  sw600dp, sw768dp?